# url autofill in the browsers

Tags: browser, autofill

in the browsers like chrome and mozilla, when we type "F" it automatically fills the url as "facebook.com", how it works, what is this concept, I want to learn this, can anyone help me by suggesting some links here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more efficient solution is to use a [prefix tree (a trie)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to store prefixes of words. That's also how spellcheck systems (such as that found in MS Word, etc) usually work.

Comment: +1 because it is a possibility, though not the only one. In Firefox if you type 'es' it automatically shows you all URLs that contain that string, and not only the ones who begin with it.